# Implement data from several data frames in one bubble plot

Tags: r, plot, bubble-chart

I have a data frame with the dimensions 625616 x 12. I would like to illustrate the data with a bubble plot. To illustrate my situation I will use the mtcars data set.

```
mtcars$cyl = as.factor(mtcars$cyl)
bp = ggplot(as.data.frame(mtcars), aes(x = wt, y = mpg, size = qsec)) + geom_point(shape = 21)
bp
```

Analogous to my data frame, I used with this command the data from 3 out of 12 columns. Ideally, I would like to add to this bubble plot another set of bubbles in another colour (column 4-6).

I tried to use the "add" function.

```
bp2 = ggplot(as.data.frame(mtcars), aes(x = wt2, y = mpg2, size = qsec2)) + geom_point(shape = 21)
plot(bp2, add = T)
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work out neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you have different `x`, `y` and `size` variables in the same data set, you can define them in the aesthetics for each `geom_point`

```
df <- data.frame(x1 = rnorm(20), y1 = rnorm(20),
             x2 = rnorm(20), y2 = rnorm(20),
             z1 =  rnorm(20), z2 = rnorm(20))

ggplot(df) +
   geom_point(aes(x = x1, y = y1, size = z1), col = "red") + 
   geom_point(aes(x = x2, y = y2, size = z2), col = "blue")
```

[image]

In case you have two distinct data sets, you can define that in the geoms as well:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x = x1, y = y1, size = z1), col = "red", data = df1) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = x2, y = y2, size = z2), col = "blue",data = df2)
```

Edit based on your comment: you can change the overall size of points by e.g. using `scale_size_continuous(range = c(0, 10))` and changing 10 to another value.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It worked out exactly as I wished.

Comment: I use scale_size(range=c(0,10)) in order to scale the size of the bubbles. Do you also know how I can customise the size of these bubbles.  It would be nice to have a way in order to customise the stepwise of the scale_size function.